# single data to predict via linear regression model with more than one categorical feature

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

I built a linear regression model to predict the sales numbers for a product,
In my case I have 5 features, 4 of them are categorical.

`MONTH REGION INTERVENANT CONFIG WEIGHT SALES_NB`

I used OneHotEncoder

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,1,2,3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X [:, 1:]
```

(correct me if I am wrong)

I want to know how do I format my data to pass it to predict().
Actually if I pass:

```
Xnew = np.array([[2,2,14895,614,0.1]])
ynew = regressor.predict(Xnew)
```

I got this error:

> ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (428,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 428 (dim 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try encoding the new sample with `onehotencoder` before you pass it to the predictor:

```
Xnew = np.array([[2,2,14895,614,0.1]])
Xnew_encoded = onehotencoder.transform(Xnew)
ynew = regressor.predict(Xnew_encoded)
```

Comment: Hello @σηγ thanks for your response i got a new error message
`ValueError: dimension mismatch`

Comment: Hello i found the problem i didn't mention this line in my question X = X [:, 1:] when i removed this line  your code works good thnks a lot.